# iOS: Nothing appears upon startup?

Tags: ios, localization, uistoryboard

I know that such question can easily be marked as off topic, but I'm sure that others could fall into the same problem and require the community help.

I was creating a Hebrew speaking app, and finally submitted it to Apple for review. It was rejected with the following message:

> Upon launching the app, it opens a blank page and the app content is
>   not loaded. In addition there is no loading indicator to suggest that
>   the app is loading.

I simply cannot understand where this is coming from!

I was testing the app on every device I could put my hands on, with any iOS between 5.1 and 9.0.2, and never got any problem. **I am not loading any resources on startup, and I always see the main screen appearing after 1 sec of loading time**. Was trying to ask the review team for more details, but got again the same message. Where can I go from here?

I was wondering if this could happen due to region selection in the device. in my  `main.c`, I'm having this right before calling `UIApplicationMain`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"he", @"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; //to make the change immediate
```

I'm doing it in order to enforce the Hebrew localization because this is the only implemented localization as for now.

However I changed both language and region to French/France and re-installed from TestFlight, and everything works as expected.

Does anyone have anything to suggest please?

Comment: Do you use network data in the application? You may have difference in network speed.

Comment: Hi @Igor. I do not use network data. All required resources are included in the bundle